# Create variables over timespan in SAS

Tags: datetime, sas

I have a dataset that includes start and end dates for a given project. I am trying to count up how many projects we are running per year and so if a project goes from 2010-2013 then it should be counted in 2010, 2011, 2012, and 2013. I am not sure how to accomplish this but I have looked into the INTCK function but I don't think that's quite what I need. Here's the data I have:

```
   Project StartDate EnDDate   UserID
   Proj1   1/15/2010 3/21/2013 1
   Proj2   7/31/2015 9/3/2018  2
```

Here's what I am looking to get:

```
   Project StartDate EnDDate   Year UserID
   Proj1   1/15/2010 3/21/2013 2010 1
   Proj1   1/15/2010 3/21/2013 2011 1
   Proj1   1/15/2010 3/21/2013 2012 1
   Proj1   1/15/2010 3/21/2013 2013 1
   ...
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: can you please tell us what code you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YEAR function and iterative DO.

```
data proj;
   input Project $ (StartDate EnDDate)(:mmddyy.) UserID;
   do year=year(startdate) to Year(enddate);
      output;
      end;
   format ST: EN: mmddyy10.;
   cards;
   Proj1   1/15/2010 3/21/2013 1
   Proj2   7/31/2015 9/3/2018  2
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it does what you're looking for:

```
data test;
 input Project $ StartDate : date9. EnDDate date9. UserID;
 format startdate enddate date9.;
 datalines;
 Proj1 15JAN2010 21MAR2013 1
 Proj2 31JUL2015 03SEP2018 2
 ;
run;

data test2;
 set test;
 do i = 0 to (year(enddate)-year(startdate));
  year = year(startdate)+i;
  drop i;
  output;
 end;
run;

proc print data=test;run;

proc print data=test2; run;
```